# A brief about Dynamic SOQL concept

Tags: dynamic-soql

can you give a complete manual/page for referring Dynamic SOQL where as https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm never providing considerable information.

```
public class DynamicSOQL { 

    public sObject sobj{set;get;} 

    public List<sObject> sobje{set;get;} 

    public void main(){ 

        String myname='KSKSK'; 

        sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from account where name=:'+myname); 

        System.debug(sobj); 
    } 
}
```

Error

> System.QueryException: sObject type 'accoount' is not supported. If
>   you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c'
>   after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names.

Comment: is there anything specific you are looking for ? means what you want to understand ? in doc everything mentioned

Comment: Yeah.. @sfdcweb

Comment: public class DynamicSOQL {
    public sObject sobj{set;get;}
    public List<sObject> sobje{set;get;}
    
    public void main(){
        String myname='Burlington Textiles Corp of America';
        sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from accoount where name=:'+myname);
        System.debug(sobj);
    }
}
This is the Exception that i am facing while executing
System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'Textiles'

Comment: can you please add your soql what you are trying and what is the error in question ?

Comment: public class DynamicSOQL {
    public sObject sobj{set;get;}
    public List<sObject> sobje{set;get;}
    
    public void main(){
        String myname='KSKSK';
        sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from accoount where name=:'+myname);
        System.debug(sobj);
    }
}
System.QueryException: sObject type 'accoount' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Its account not accoount

Comment: public class DynamicSOQL {
    public sObject sobj{set;get;}
    public List<sObject> sobje{set;get;}
    
    public void main(){
        sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from account where name=Burlington Textiles Corp of America');
        System.debug(sobj);
    }
}

System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'Burlington'

Comment: String myname='KSKSK'; 
        sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from accoount where name=:\'myname\'');
While executing the class by using above query, getting this error
System.QueryException: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic SOQL/SOSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SOQL queries are queries which are built on the fly like built by getting inputs from user selection.

It can use apex bind variables just like static SOQL by using : and reference the bind variable.

If there is no bind variable, then you need to provide values without :.

If the value references string, then you need to escape it.

Putting all together,

1. Dynamic SOQL with apex bind variable

   ```
   String myname='Burlington Textiles Corp of America';
   sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from account where name=:myname');
   ```
2. Dynamic SOQL without apex bind variable

   ```
   sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from account where name=\'Burlington Textiles Corp of America\'');
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sobje=Database.query('select id,phone from account where name=\\'Burlington Textiles Corp of America\\'');

expecting a right parentheses, found 'Burlington'

Comment: My bad. Its single \ not \\.

Comment: I got it 
Thank you so much

Comment: By performing all above, i got one doubt.
please explain me what is bind variables in dynamic soql